# How to disable/bypass JBoss EWS 2.0 logging on OpenShift?

Tags: jboss, jvm, log4j, openshift, jvm-arguments

I am able to deploy a war on OpenShift using git (git add, push ...) and it works. The only problem that I encountered is that all my logs are doubled (only when I deploy on OpenShift) whereas locally (using apache tomcat 7 with only log4j framework) all my logs are only logged one time.

After having searched one day on the Internet, I have found two ways to normally fix that problem, which is to find how to disable/bypass JBoss EWS 2.0 logging on OpenShift:

---

**Clues found on Google**

---

1) Add a JAVA_OPT to Startup

Now, when starting the application server, you will need to add a JAVA_OPT.  This flag will make sure that the JBoss Log Manager does not pick up your logging configuration and your own logging JARs will work as normal.

```
./standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

And now your application will now log using the packaged JARs, effectively bypassing JBoss Logging.

Source: http://blog.jyore.com/?p=234

2) It looks like you have a log4j configuration file in your deployment. Try passing

```
-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

to disable that configuration from being used.

--
James R. Perkins

Source: https://community.jboss.org/thread/224127

---

**My implementation of these clues**

---

For implementing these solutions I did two things:

1) I created and git push this hook below:

`vim .openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_jbossews-2.0`

`echo "executing pre_start_jbossews-2.0"`

`# I also tried with JAVA_OPTS`

`export JAVA_OPTS_EXT="-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"`

`echo "Value is: $JAVA_OPTS_EXT"`

Note: this hook is well triggered, because I can see the echo when the server restarts after having pushed the modifications.

2) I also added this line in catalina.properties:

```
vim .openshift/config/catalina.properties 
-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

Conclusion at that time:

Unfortunately none of these solutions disable/bypass JBoss EWS 2.0 default logging.
I am currently stuck with double log lines, so any help would be greatly appreciated, I count on you guys.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On Openshift the right way to setup persistent environment values is to use `rhc` tool:

`rhc set-env JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false -a myapp`

Then try to explicitly stop and start your application (with rhc stop and rhc start).

Comment: Actually the command line that you gave me works very well for setting the environment variable on OpenShift, but was not enough sufficient for fixing my issue (after having followed all the steps of this tutorial http://bit.ly/1rPuiDS). Does not matter because since I decided to give up and scrap JBoss EWS 2.0 for replacing it with a diy cartridge with Apache Tomcat v7. Thanks anyway.